# Getting value of a select results undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, razor-pages

I have a select with options and id. With a function im trying to get the value of this select on onClick function. In function i alert the data but it's either undefined or empty. My select:

```
  <select class="form-control" id="labels" onchange="chng()">
                    <option>Extra Label</option>
                    @for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++)
                    {
                        <option>@i</option>
                    }
                </select>
```

and my onClick function:

```
function chng() {
    var selectedValue = document.getElementById('labels').value;
    var v = $('#labels').val();
    alert(v);
    alert(selectedValue);
    var addLabelsBtn = document.getElementById('addLabelsBtn');
    addLabelsBtn.href = '/Amazon/AddLabel?orderId=@Model.AmazonOrderId&extraLabel=' + selectedValue;

}
```

I tried both **getElemenyById** and **.val()**. **getElementById** gives **undefined** and **.val()** gives **empty**.

Comment: You appear to have jQuery on your page? (probably NOT needed...)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I have it in my Layout

Answer (score 2):

Plain JavaScript, attach the event listener in the code not the markup. I guessed at what you called a "button" was really an anchor tag `<a>` since you have tried to add an href.

I did a console log just to show the changed element.

```js
const select = document.querySelector('#labels');
select.addEventListener('change', handleChange);

function handleChange(event) {
  const selectedValue = this.value;
  const addLabelsBtn = document.getElementById('addLabelsBtn');
  addLabelsBtn.href = '/Amazon/AddLabel?orderId=@Model.AmazonOrderId&extraLabel=' + selectedValue;
  console.log(addLabelsBtn);
}
```

```css
.button {
  display: inline;
  width: 10em;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: #4E9CAF40;
  padding: 0.625em;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 1em;
  color: #0000ff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="labels">
  <option value="0">Extra Label</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
  <option>11</option>
  <option>12</option>
  <option>13</option>
  <option>14</option>
  <option>15</option>
  <option>16</option>
  <option>17</option>
  <option>18</option>
  <option>19</option>
  <option>20</option>
</select>

<a class="button" id="addLabelsBtn">Howdy</a>
```

Comment: Probably want the `<option>Extra Label</option>` disabled so it cannot be "selected" but that is not part of the question.

Comment: It did not even get in handleChange()

Comment: umm, run this snippet and it does; if NOT you have something else in play that you have NOT posted;